# How to remove String value from a String at First Character in java?

Tags: java

I want to remove countrycode which contains **+91** from mobileNumber at first three characters only.

```
String countrycode = +91;

String mobileNumber = 123917890;

if (mobileNumber.contains(countrycode)){
    int v = countrycode.length();
    String phonenumber = mobileNumber.substring(v);
    System.out.println(phonenumber);
} else {
    System.out.println("mobile number doesn't have country code");
}
```

But in mycode it removing **91** from mobileNumber if it's contains in whole String.

getting output:

```
3917890
```

But I want to remove countrycode at first String three characters if contains. How should I create that type of condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can use String replace to replace the +91 with blank if found

```
String countrycode = +91;

String mobileNumber = 123917890;

String noCountryCode = mobileNumber.replace("+91", "");

System.out.println(noCountryCode);
```

Comment: thank you for helping me, I got proper condition for it. Please check my answer once and give me your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer, thankyou to all for helping me

just simple

```
String countrycode = +91;

String mobileNumber = 123917890;

if (mobileNumber.contains("+" + countrycode)){
                    int v = countrycode.length();
                    String phonenumber = num_code.substring(v);
                    System.out.println(phonenumber);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("mobile number doesn't have country code");
                }
```

now it's working as expected result.